Test for effect on an experiment on a 2X2 table
I am running an experiment to change the endpoint of a test for internet connectivity. The test can succeed or fail and in the current live situation can go to one of two servers (say server1 and server2) with a 50% probability.
The experiment runs on a small sample of tests and is to see if changing one of the endpoints would lead to a significant change in the test results. The experiment sends 50% of its tests to the new version of server1, but leaves server2 as it is.
So to my mind this gives me a 2X2X2 table with the dimensions being server, experiment / current and succeed / fail.
The success rates for the experiment and the current version to the server that doesn't change (server2) are different due to other random effects that I am not interested in and largely don't have access to.
So what I want to know is what statistical test could I do that would tell me whether the differences with server1 in the experiment are significant, given the differences I see in server2?

It's not clear to me what you mean by current/experiment and how you get an extra dimension from this, but otherwise this sounds a lot like McNemar's test. At a minimum, that might be a good starting point for your search.

I am not sure how you get to a 3D table; you really have only a 2x2 table (server1/2, pass/fail) (experiment vs. current is the same as server1 vs. server2). So this should be a classic 2x2 contingency table, which can be tested with Fisher-exact, or possibly $\chi^2$, if assumption for the binomial being well approximated by a gaussian hold. This will tell you if the proportion of "pass" on server 1 is significantly larger than for server2 (I assume you want to show the "experiment" increases thge proportion of "pass"; so run a single sided test for extra power).
